# Provoking extended conversation with an individual member by asking a question directed at them

Tags: discussion, questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117172/babcock-talk-to-me-about-ebay-and-c-sharp) (deleted now so only users with the necessary privilege can see it) is obviously ridiculous, but it is pointed at *me* so I have trouble ignoring it. What is the **right** way to handle this?

Comment: There's already a delete vote on it. So just sit and relax. :)

Comment: I have no problem doing that, but it is definitely frustrating (if not _humiliating_) to be called out in such a manner. I did flag it but knowing that the SO flag queue is always running on full who knows when it'll clear.

Comment: There, took care of it for you. I casted the last delete vote.

Comment: You could have edited out your name.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not quite to that 10K mark to have any say myself.

Comment: That's my delete vote, and you should rest assured that the OP is making a fool of the him or her self, not you. That said, a mod flag would have been justified.

Comment: @JayRiggs - You're right but I didn't in fear of starting a rollback war.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - I appreciate the support.

Comment: Obviously wasn't directed at you... They didn't even spell your name correctly.

Comment: @TheEstablishment - No one ever does, but it was close enough that to draw my attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your course of action is correct. Just flag it and let the 20ks and mods handle it.

If it's egregious enough, posting here on meta (as you have done) will definitely speed the process up since you bring a new set of eyes upon it.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In the case that it's a real question but directed at you: Edit your name out, leave a comment that you're not the *only* guy on SO.

In this case, the question is one that really should be a comment (and that's  if we're being lax about comment rules). Conversations go to chat in a perfect world.

You should have flagged the question AND cast a close/delete vote (close in this case, since you're 7k)

Whenever a user gets too naggy/tangential/offtopic in the comments/questions, just ignore him/her. I find that the best course of action.

Comment: Sounds like I did the right thing then; commented, downvoted, voted to close, then flagged for mod attention. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Meh, I'd skip the commenting unless you actually *want* to engage with the person. Once you've commented, that opens the door for them to `@reply` you, and that's just annoying.

Comment: @TheEstablishment - I agree, though I felt obligated considering the whole question was directed at me.

Comment: @M.Bab *That's what they want you to feel!* Fight the power! (...oh wait is that maybe ironic?)

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Good point.. Though there ought to be a way to turn of pinging for a thread..

Comment: @Manishearth: There is. You'll discover it when you get to 20k. They've cleverly disguised it by calling it "delete".

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Aah.. Hate the privilege system at times :/ ... Though sometimes "delete" isn't what you want--especially during post-hijacks.

Comment: @TheEstablishment - Of course, you're right and my comment only caused the OP to engage me again (as you mentioned) but then it's just the simple task of ignoring any other comments. I mastered that already with him on his previous question (perhaps that is what caused this whole thing... hmmm).